# Using SQL to determine checks received

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to wrap my brain around a solution to the following query I need to create:

I have a table called `CHK_HIST_HEADER` that stores the summary information of each check an employee gets. The employee is identified in this table as `ID_NUM`. There are obviously many records per `ID_NUM`, as each employee has typically received multiple checks. I need to determine which employees have received a check on a specified date (e.g. `3/31/2014`), but prior to that have **NOT** received a check at all, OR have not received a check within the 60 days prior to the specified date (e.g. `>= 1/30/2014`).

So, for example, if Employee ID `1234` received a check on `3/31/2014` but have never received a check prior to that, they would be included.
In addition, employee ID 2345 received a check on 3/31/2014 and `5/15/2013`, so they would be included, since `5/15/2013` is more than 60 days prior to `3/31/2014`.

Employee ID 5678 received a check on `3/31/2014` and `3/15/3014`, so they would `NOT` be included in the results.

The check date field is `CHK_HIST_HEADER.CHECK_DTE`. The specified date is a variable called `@CheckDate` which is chosen by the user, but `3/31/2014` will work for any examples.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.CHK_HIST_HEADER A
WHERE SomeColumnDate = '20140331' -- assuming this column is a DATE
AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM dbo.CHK_HIST_HEADER
                WHERE ID_NUM = A.ID_NUM
                AND SomeColumnDate >= DATEADD(DAY,-60,'20140331')
                AND SomeColumnDate < '20140331')
```